# Using three.js with blender- embed .json files

Tags: three.js, blender

I installed the three.js exporter. When I export a blender model I get a model.json file. I tried to replace the model in this example/tutorial http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-beginners-guide-to-three-js with my model, but it is not shown... how do I have to embed the exported .json files?
thanks and regards
Adriana

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer. Try to import your model to [editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) and see if it works. If not - there is problem with your model. If it works - there problems with your code.

Are you using the whole code from [example](http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/threejs_logo_example/index.html)?
Or are your trying to reproduce it?
Then maybe your path to model is wrong or there is issue with three.js version. Is there any console errors in your project?

Answer (score 0):

What version of three.js are you using? If r70 the exporter defaults to `Scene` (JSONLoader expects geometry format and not scene format) exports so you will need to uncheck that option during export. Additionally I would suggest using the exporter in the `dev` branch of three.js as it has undergone loads of bug fixes, additionally the export defaults to geometry exports.

Comment: thanks... I don't know what exactly it was, but when I switched to blender 2.69 and used the current three.js exporter, it suddenly worked. (besides errors I got while trying to export some option as scene etc. in blender- with geometry only it worked)